# Prove that $f$ is integrable given that f is a positive measurable function on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f∈L^p$, where $p∈[1,∞)$ and $y$ given, for all $y > 2$.
>   Let $f$ be a positive measurable function on $[0,1]$ satisfying
>   $$μ \left[{x∈[0,1]:f(x)>y}\right] \le \frac{1}{y} \frac{1}{\log(y)^2}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is integrable.

How do I construct the proper bounded $E_n$?

Comment: Since the function is on the interval, a finite measure space, we have $L_p\subseteq L_q$ if $p>q$. Choose $q=1$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, I consider the case p > 1, such that I construct a sequence of disjoint sets such that E_n = {x∈[0,1] | ...}. How do I bound my f(x) function here?

Comment: {2^(n-1) < f(x) < 2^n} s.t. {0 ≤ f(x) ≤1} for n = 0?